# Django 2.0 upgrade caused Wagtail (2.1) admin to disappear.

Tags: django, wagtail

I was in the process of upgrading my wagtail app to Django 2.0. After resolving the on-delete errors I thought I had a working app until I went to the /admin page. The standard Wagtail admin interface has disappeared and has been replaced by the default Django admin interface. Can anyone help?

https://github.com/timcknowles/wagtailcmsdemo/tree/django2

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your `urls.py` has the Django admin before the Wagtail admin](https://github.com/timcknowles/wagtailcmsdemo/blob/fe70c9dd86a9231a3b69ef724bba1f8aec0aef5c/acoidea/urls.py#L14-L16), so the Django admin "wins out".

Swap the order of those two, or maybe rename the Django admin prefix to `^djangoadmin/`.

Comment: Thanks so much. That's sorted it.

Comment: I always map Wagtail to be `/cms/` to avoid conflicts with the Django admin. I wish it would become a convention. :)